# How to preserve scroll position after goto function in Sapper?

Tags: scroll, sapper, svelte-3

After navigation using `goto()` function in Sapper the scroll top position sets back to zero. Is there an easy way to control this. Specially when using `replaceState: true`. Its a bit odd that scroll top sets back to zero with `replaceState: true` option.

Edit: Also input fields also lose focus after `goto(/url, {replaceState: true})`. I feel this behavior is odd. With `replaceState: true` option. `goto()` should preserve these (scroll poisition.. input focus.. etc.) or Maybe..

Edit-2: This is also the behavior of `history.replaceState()`. Is doesn't lose scroll position and input field focus.